# How to implement Post/Redirect/Get in django pagination?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a view that filters out results for a posted search form:

```
def profile_advanced_search(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.POST)
        qs=[]
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            s_country=cd['country']
            s_province=cd['province']
            s_city = cd['city']

            if s_country: qs.append(Q(country__icontains = s_country))    
            if s_province: qs.append( Q(province__icontains=s_province))                
            if s_city: qs.append( Q(city__icontains=s_city))



            f = None
            for q in qs:
                if f is None: 
                    f=q 

                else: f &=q
            list = UserProfile.objects.filter(f).order_by('-created_at') 


    else:
        form = AdvancedSearchForm()
        list = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')

    paginator = Paginator(list,10)            
    page= request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        results = paginator.page(1)  

    except EmptyPage:
            results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)        

    args.update(csrf(request))    
    args['form'] = form  
    args['results'] = results
    return render_to_response('userprofile/advanced_search.html', args,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the urls.py part is:

```
url(r'^search/$', 'userprofile.views.profile_advanced_search'),
```

The template is:

```
  <form action="/search/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

              <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li><h3>Country</h3></li>
                <li>{{form.country}}</li><br> 
                <h4>Province</h4>
                <li>{{form.province}}</li>
                  <h4>City</h4>
                <li>{{form.city}}</li>


              </ul>

    <input  type="submit" name="submit"  value="search" />

     </form>
         Search Results:
    {% for p in results %}

                <div">
                      <div>
                          <br>
                           <strong><a href="/profile/{{p.username}}" >{{p.username}}</a></strong>
                             {{p.country}} <br>
                             {{p.province}} <br>
                             {{p.city}} <br>

                         </div>
                      </div>
    {% endfor %}



    <div>
        <div class="pagination">
          {% if results.has_previous %}
              <a href="?page={{ results.previous_page_number }}"> << Prev </a>&nbsp;&nbsp
          {% endif %}

           {% if results.has_next %}
              <a href="?page={{ results.next_page_number }}"> Next >> </a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

These work fine for the first page, but to deal with the later pages, it is [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751000/django-pagination-in-filtered-search-post-results/28751546#28751546) that I need to implement Post/Redirect/Get .

However I have had difficulty to make such views/template/urls to deal with GET pages regarding that all of the search parameters are arbitrary. So I appreciate a complete solution.

Comment: Be careful, **this site is not a complete-code service**, you should be able to get a solution at [referenced answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751000/django-pagination-in-filtered-search-post-results/28751546#28751546). If my new answer contains mistakes, improve it, please don't ask to me more help about this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need **2** views. First one for form search and second one to show results. You have not implemented redirect in any way in your sample code!

**urls**

```
...
url(r'^search/$', 
    'userprofile.views.profile_advanced_search'),
url(r'^show/(?P<country>\w+)/(?P<province>\w+)/(?P<site>\w+)/(?P<page>\d+)',
    'userprofile.views.profile_advanced_show'),
...
```

**profile_advanced_search**

```
def profile_advanced_search(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.POST)
        qs=[]
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            s_country=cd['country']
            s_province=cd['province']
            s_city = cd['city']

            return HttpResponseRedirect(
               reverse('userprofile.views.profile_advanced_show', 
                        args=(s_country, s_province, s_city, 0, )))

   return HttpResponseRedirect(
               reverse('userprofile.views.profile_advanced_show', 
                        args=('+', '+', '+', 0, )))
```

**profile_advanced_show**

```
def profile_advanced_show(request, s_country='', 
                          s_province='', s_city='', page=0):
    f = some filters with s_country, s_province and s_city
    list = UserProfile.objects.filter(f).order_by('-created_at') 

    paginator = Paginator(list,10)            
    try:
        results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        results = paginator.page(1)  

    except EmptyPage:
        results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)        

    args.update(csrf(request))    
    form = AdvancedSearchForm(initial={ 's_country': s_country, ... } )
    args['form'] = form  
    args['results'] = results
    return render_to_response('userprofile/advanced_search.html', args,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Notice: improve it for not valid form submissions. Remember you can send parameters to second view via GET as key value instead route values.